# Loading a script after page loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, algolia

I know there are some threads out there about this, but I haven't figured it out yet.

I have a script that I need it to load after the page was loaded, because I don't have access to my website's HTML. I tried a few things which are shown below. However keep in mind that I'm not exactly a JS programmer so it's also possible that the code is missing some stuff (like: `; || ) || }` etc) so this is the function I need to run after page was loaded:

```
 (function() {
    var placesAutocomplete = places({
      appId: 'I have it',
      apiKey: 'I have it',
      container: document.querySelector('input[name="address-line1"]'),
      templates: {
        value: function(suggestion) {
          return suggestion.name;
        }
      }
    }).configure({
      type: 'address'
     });
 }());
```

appreciate the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.onload for loading a script after page loaded

```
window.onload = function(){
//your code here
};
```

Comment: could you perhaps show me how the code should look like? I mean copy-paste my code into your suggestion.